# Is it possible to use variables inside PostgreSQL stored procedures that are using SQL language?

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible to use variables inside PostgreSQL stored procedures that are using SQL language?

If possible, how to assign them with results from a select and use them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a SQL language function can return a scalar value, if that is what you SELECT, but there are no variables in a SQL function.  (The closest I can think of is using a CTE.)

If you use language plpgsql then you can declare variables.